# Ready API (v2.4) integration with TFS for code repo

Tags: tfs, soapui, tfs-2015, ready-api

I am very new to API automation through ready API , I want to store all my code on TFS but ,I couldn't find any doc or video as to how to do it , although there are many docs and sources available as to how to do it on git HUB but not on TFS, Need your help on same

I am currently using Ready API 2.4 version and TFS 2017

Request you to guide me on this

Comment: Hi Chandan, How about this issue? Does below answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Answer (score 1):

Found this official doc: [Git Integration](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/git/index.html), which guides you to store tests and test projects in source control, so you could store all code on TFS by connecting to Remote TFS 2017 Repository and clone it.